# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\tugas1\m_programKerja.php on line 43

Tags: model-view-controller, mysqli, null

i know this question has been asked a lot, and i have been searching the answer to my question for days but i still havent found it yet.

when i run index.php, it says Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\tugas1\m_programKerja.php on line 43. Am i getting the error because i havent inserted anything on my table on database? I did insert some data but i still got this error though...

here's the code:
koneksiMVC.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "praktikumweb");
?>
```

m_programKerja.php

```
<?php

class m_programKerja {

public $hasil = array();
private $mysqli;

public function __construct() {
    require 'koneksiMVC.php';
}

public function setPogramKerja($nomorProgram, $namaProgram, $suratKeterangan) {
    $rs = $this->mysqli->query( "INSERT INTO proker VALUES   
                                ($nomorProgram,
                                 '$namaProgram',
                                 '$suratKeterangan')
                                ");
}

public function hapusProgramKerja($nomorProgram) {
    $rs = $this->mysqli->query( "DELETE from proker WHERE 
                                    nomorProgram = $nomorProgram
                                ");
}

public function editProgramKerja($nomorProgram, $namaProgram, $suratKeterangan) {
    $rs = $this->mysqli->query( "UPDATE proker 
                                    SET namaProgram = '$namaProgram',
                                        suratKeterangan= '$suratKeterangan'
                                    WHERE nomorProgram = $nomorProgram
                                ");
}

public function getPogramKerja($nomorProgram) {
    $rs = $this->mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM proker
                                    WHERE nomorProgram = $nomorProgram
                                ");
    $this->hasil = $rs->fetch_array();
    return $this->hasil;
}

public function getSemuaPogramKerja() {
    $rs = $this->mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM proker "); //this is line 43

    while ($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
        $this->hasil[] = $row;
    }
    return $this->hasil;
}
}
?>
```

and index.php

```
<?php
include_once("c_programKerja.php");
$controller = new c_programKerja();
if (isset($_GET['d'])) {
$controller->delete($_GET['d']);
} else if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
$controller->viewUpdate($_GET['u']);
} else if (isset($_GET['i'])) {
$controller->viewInsert();
} else {
$controller->invoke();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because your `$mysqli` object is likely null on your lines: `$rs = $this->mysqli->query(`...

Are you certain you are including/executing the contents of `koneksiMVC.php` where `$mysqli` is supposed to be set? Try just moving `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "praktikumweb");` down into your document on its own. instead of loading it from a page within a function call.

Also, just after you instantiate your `mysqli` object, add the following lines, like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "praktikumweb");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

This will print out if there were any connection related errors and stop execution.

Comment: Maybe it is just a typo on your question, but in your `index.php`, you have `c_programKerja.php` for your include, but above you have your code labeled as `m_programKerja.php` and you are instantiating a new `c_programKerja`. Are we looking at the correct section of code?

Comment: could you include the contents of that document/class, or include the document that calls your `m_programKerja` class? Right now, we aren't comparing the same things, so there is no way to determine where the error is actually occurring, and what would be causing it.

Comment: @Krystal I updated my answer with a small suggestion to trap any errors that may occur when creating an instance of your data connection `mysqli` object.